# Python: Partial sum of numbers

Tags: python

can you help me with code which returns partial sum of numbers in text file? 
I must import text file, then make a code for partial sums without tools ..etc.

My input:

```
4
13
23
21
11
```

The output should be (without brackets or commas):

```
4 
17
40
61 
72
```

I was trying to make code in python, but could only do total sum and not partial one. 
If i use the `+=` operator for generator, it gives me an error!

Comment: Do you want an array result, or just printed output?

Comment: Behold: `reduce(lambda c, x: c + [c[-1] + x], [4, 13, 23, 21, 11], [0])[1:]`

Answer (score 27):

Well, since everyone seems to be giving their favourite idiom for solving the problem, how about [itertools.accumulate](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) in Python 3:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> nums = [4, 13, 23, 21, 11]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(nums))
[4, 17, 40, 61, 72]
```

Comment: Note: "new in version 3.2". Interesting addition. :)

Comment: @hayden: it's even better in 3.3.  3.2 doesn't accept a function parameter.

Comment: I particularly like how `total = next(it)` deals with the `[]` case...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know they were adding this. Too bad the 3.3 version has `func` as the _second_ argument -- I would have expected them to make it consistent with `map` and `reduce` (and almost all the other itertools functions that accept functions as arguments).

Comment: It should be printed output ( without brackets ), and for some to me unknown reason i cant import itertools. Can it be done any other way?

Comment: @DSM I can't wait! @senderle consistency is one argument, but frequency of use is another - you always need a function to `map` or `reduce` and there is really no meaningful default, but `accumulate` will normally be used for partial sums.

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of ways to create your sequence of partial sums. I think the most elegant is to use a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

```
def partial_sums(iterable):
    total = 0
    for i in iterable:
        total += i
        yield total
```

You can run it like this:

```
nums = [4, 13, 23, 21, 11]
sums = list(partial_sums(nums)) # [ 4, 17, 40, 61, 72]
```

**Edit** To read the data values from your file, you can use another generator, and chain them together. Here's how I'd do it:

```
with open("filename.in") as f_in:
    # Sums generator that "feeds" from a generator expression that reads the file
    sums = partial_sums(int(line) for line in f_in)

    # Do output:
    for value in sums:
        print(value)

    # If you need to write to a file, comment the loop above and uncomment this:
    # with open("filename.out", "w") as f_out:
    #    f_out.writelines("%d\n" % value for value in sums)
```

Comment: This is probably the most useful answer for the OP.

Comment: @user1798558: if this answer helped you, you can thank the author by selecting the green checkmark on the left (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for instructions.)

Answer (score 6):

[`numpy.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy.cumsum) will do what you want.

If you're not using `numpy`, you can write your own.

```
def cumsum(i):
    s = 0
    for elt in i:
        s += elt
        yield s
```

Comment: I don't think adding a dependency on numpy is a good idea unless he's already using it.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

input = [ 4, 13, 23, 21, 11 ]
output = []
output.append(input[0])
for i in np.arange(1,len(input)):
    output.append(input[i] + input[i-1])

print output
```

Answer (score 2):

Use cumulative sum in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([4, 13, 23, 21 ,11])
output = input.cumsum()
```

Result:

```
print output
>>>array([ 4, 17, 40, 61, 72])
```

Or if you need a list, you may convert output to list:

```
output = list(output)
print output
>>>[4, 17, 40, 61, 72]
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
>>> lst = [4, 13, 23, 21 ,11]
>>> [sum(lst[:i+1]) for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
[4, 17, 40, 61, 72]
```

Comment: -1 This computes `sum([4])`, then `sum([4,13])`, then `sum([4,13,23])`, etc -- defeating the point of taking a cumulative sum!

Comment: I wouldn't say that it defeats the purpose.  It's an inefficient way to compute it (O(n^2) instead of O(n)) but it gets the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
nums = [4, 13, 23, 21, 11]
partial_sum = lambda a, b: a + [a[-1] + b]
sums = reduce(partial_sum, nums[1:], nums[0:1])
```

Pluses in lambda are not the same operator, the first one is list concatenation and the second one is sum of two integers. Altough Blckknght's may be more clear, this one is shorter and works in Python 2.7.