# Using list comprehension to store the maximum seen value

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to do the below with list comprehension? Trying to store the maximum value that has been seen at any given point through the loop.

```
def test(input):
    a = input[0]
    b = []
    for i in input:
        a = max(i,a)
        b.append(a)
    return b

print test([-5,6,19,4,5,20,1,30])

# returns [-5, 6, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 30]
```

Comment: [max(i, a) for i, a in enumerate(your_list)]

Comment: @sergzach: mind that `i` is the index. Here the **thus far** max is wanted.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah, right, my bad.

Comment: You can't do it with a "plain" list comprehension, because the list comprehension itself won't maintain state (like the highest seen so far).  You can only do it if your list comprehension applies a function that maintains state (like `itertools.accumulate`), or if you run your function on chunks of the list instead of individual elements (as in Willem Van Onsem's O(n^2) example.

Comment: The duplicate is not exactly a duplicate. It is correct that both questions have the same structure, but they address different operations.

Comment: @DYZ - Yes, it is a duplicate. All you have to change is choosing an appropriate function, which the OP of this question has already done.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I doubt if people looking for a solution to this same problem  will find solace in that dupe target.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - They will, unless they're (mis)using this site as a free coding service.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - Do you honestly think that replacing `operator.add` with `max` makes this a unique question? Removing the convenient duplicate link just forces future visitors to take a little longer to find the information they're looking for.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [List comprehension with an accumulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20222485)  Note: The accepted answer on that question as been updated with an explanation since when this question was previously marked as a duplicate. With the explanation, particularly of how passing a function to `itertools.accumulate` works, it's much easier to tell that this question is a duplicate, just with a different accumulator function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List comprehension with an accumulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222485/list-comprehension-with-an-accumulator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you present here is a typical form of what is known in *functional programming* as `scan`.

A way to do this with *list comprehension* that is **inefficient** is:

```
[max(input[:i]) for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

But this will run in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

You can do this with list comprehension given you **use a function with side effects**: like the following:

```
def update_and_store(f,initial=None):
    cache = [initial]
    def g(x):
       cache[0] = f(cache[0],x)
       return cache[0]
    return g
```

You can then use:

```
h = update_and_store(max,a[0])
[h(x) for x in a]
```

Or you can use a dictonaries `setdefault()` like:

```
def update_and_store(f):
    c = {}
    def g(x):
        return c.setdefault(0,f(c.pop(0,x),x))
    return g
```

and call it with:

```
h = update_and_store(max)
[h(x) for x in a]
```

like [@AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162741/possible-to-do-in-list-comprehension-max-value-seen-so-far/43162806?noredirect=1#comment73400616_43162806) says.

But functions with *side-effects* are rather *unpythonic* and not *declarative*.

But you better use a `scanl` or `accumulate` approach like the one offered by [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

accumulate(input,max)
```

Comment: Just as a trick. You can implement the `update_and_store()` with a `dict`: `c = {}; [c.setdefault(0, max(c.pop(0, n), n)) for n in d]`

Comment: @AChampion: yeah. That is indeed a smart way to do this. Nevertheless regardless on how one implements functions with side-effects, they are almost inherently dangerous to use in list-comprehension, generators, etc. So I would not recommend using them anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) builtin in Python 3:

```
from itertools import accumulate

lst = [-5,6,19,4,5,20,1,30]
r = list(accumulate(lst, max)) #[i for i in accumulate(lst, max)]
print(r)
# [-5, 6, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 30]
```

Comment: With `list(accumulate(...))` you can avoid the explicit list comprehension.

Comment: @DYZ Brainfart. Got carried away by the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If using NumPy is permitted, then you can use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
np.maximum.accumulate([-5,6,19,4,5,20,1,30])
# array([-5,  6, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 30])
```